# When is "mitad" appropriate?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Another thing I'm often corrected on is my apparent overuse of the word *medio*. What are the proper uses of the words *mitad* (and *la mitad*) and *medio* (and *el medio*)?

Comment: Please name some examples you use with both *mitad* and *medio*, so we can assess them.

Comment: @Petruza: The only example I can recall is the song [Mi media mitad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQUcaSEuob0) and I've always thought it sounded wrong.

Comment: @JaimeSoto: why wrong? *media* is half as an adjective, and *mitad* is half as a noun, so *media mitad* is effectively *half of a half*, I.E. a quarter.

Comment: @Petruza: It sounds wrong in the context of the song. I doubt the author meant to say _She's my 25%_ in the phrase _Ella fué mi media mitad_.

Comment: @Petruza: I don't understand your question; I'm not asking about when to use _both_, but when to use either.

Comment: @Flimzy: That's what I meant, please give examples of how you use *mitad* and *medio*. I meant *both* just for enumerating the words, not that you used them together.

Comment: I think the answer provided below has good examples.  Do you feel the answer needs something more to justify changing the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These have a few different meanings depending on the presence or absence of `el`/`la`.

> *Un medio día* = a half day.
>
> *En el medio de la muchedumbre* = in the middle of the crowd

But I wouldn't really say it this way; I think *el medio* is less commonly-used. I would say *En el centro de la muchedumbre* in that case, for example.

I've never seen *mitad* alone. Its use is pretty specific. Use it when **half** needs to operate as a noun.

> *Deme la mitad* = Give me half

They're distinct words; the uses and meanings don't really overlap as such other than that they both sometimes translate to **half** in English.

Comment: *la mitad* = half, when operating as a noun.  I think that was the missing piece.  Thank you!

Comment: It's "la muchedumbre", not "el muchedumbre". [DRAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=muchedumbre)

Comment: Fixed. @MikMik You should be able to propose an edit to my post by clicking the edit link. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinK.: the fix is less than 6 characters, only you can fix it, neither MikMik nor I have enough reputation to do so.